# "Irreparable damage" vs. "irrecoverable damage"

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

Which word is a better fit in the following sentence?

> Some of the environmental changes may produce **irreparable/irrecoverable** damage to the earth's capacity to sustain life.

Comment: [irreprable](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/irreparable) vs [irrecoverable](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/irrecoverable). Please read [this post](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2012/09/writing-good-meaning-questions/) on how to ask good meaning questions.

Answer (score 3):

*irreparable* (OED: "Too far decayed to be repaired; past repair.") describes the level of damage something has sustained. It is damaged so extensively that it cannot be repaired in any way. A car could be irreparable.

*irrecoverable* (OED: "That cannot be recovered or got back: chiefly in reference to things lost.")describes loss, specifically the ability to revert to a previous state. Data on a hard-drive may be irrecoverable if it has been written over, but there is no sense of damage.

*Irreparable* and *irrecoverable* are not synonyms.

If the previously mentioned hard-drive has endured a fire and suffered irreparable damage, the data it contained is very likely irrecoverable, but note that *irreparable* describes the state of the hard-drive, while *irrecoverable* describes the state of the information.

Comment: So what will be the correct word in context of damage?

Answer (score 1):

M-W.com says this:

> **irrecoverable**: not capable of being recovered or rectified : **irreparable** [an irrecoverable loss]

So they appear to be synonymous. Perhaps you can think of the difference in these two words this way:

1. The damage cannot be repaired.
2. The {environment / Earth / ecosystem} will not recover from the damage.

I would use **irreparable** in your example sentence: *Some of the environmental changes may produce **irreparable** damage to the earth's capacity to sustain life* because the adjective modifies *damage*: once the damage is done, it cannot be undone. The earth's capacity to sustain life will be diminished, and that lost capacity cannot be recovered.